# Multiplying tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples, multiplication

I need to create a nested tuple in which some values are the same, so I tried multiplying them.

```
t = ((('a', 'b'),) * 3)
print t
```

Prints

```
(('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b'))
```

Is there a syntactically nicer way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the outer parentheses? They're not doing anything; they're just grouping parentheses, like in `(1 + 2) * 3`, but in a context where they don't help disambiguate any grouping.

Comment: My thinking was that they were necessary to create the outer tuple, rather than for any grouping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is not using as many brackets:

```
t = (('a', 'b'), ) * 3
```

works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

The representation of that expression could be slightly simpler but it's almost canonical. I would use

```
t = 3 * (('a', 'b'), )
```

which removes one set of parentheses and visually warns about the multiplication before showing the tuple. You might imagine a further set of parentheses can be removed to give

```
t = 3 * ('a', 'b'),
```

but alas the result of this expression is not the required one, instead giving

```
(('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'),)
```

*i.e.* a tuple whose only element is the six generated elements.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
t = (('a', 'b'),)*3
```

ie, simply remove the brackets and its done

Answer (score 1):

Another choice:

```
from  itertools import repeat
tuple(repeat(('a', 'b'), 3))
```